# Background image not showing HTML CSS

Tags: html, css

So I'm having a little bit of difficulty with my background image in one section of my site. I've tried adding quotes, adding .../, everything, and it still doesn't seem to work... All my files for my site are in file "project09" with the images inside folder "imgs". The path is correct because all the other images in the code are showing up, just not this particular one.

Here is the relevant code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0px; /* always zero out defaul browser margins and padding */
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: 'Saira Extra Condensed', sans-serif;
  color: #4587a7;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#splash{
  height: 100px;
  background: url(imgs/heron.jpg) no-repeat center top;
  background-size: cover;
}

.container {
  width: 960px; 
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#title-page{
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 200px; 
  text-align: left;
  color: #FFF2CC;
}
```

```html
<section id="splash">
    <div id="title-page"> 
        <div class="container">
            <h1> Environmental Issues<br>in Florida</h1>
        </div> 
    </div> 
</section>
```

Comment: Do you see it gets image in network ? You can use chrome dev tools - network tab to see. Are you serving from file system or local dev server?

Comment: Where’s your css located?

Comment: What is full file path of where your background image lives. Your probably calling this location wrong; and or your CSS. Put your code in a jsfiddle.net and post it here.

Comment: the full path is project09/imgs/heron.jpg
http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=mEjET71ruN

Comment: css is located within "project09"

Comment: Remove `height` **and** `background-size` from your CSS. Do you see it then?

Comment: removed height and bacground-size but still not there...

Comment: So you can insert another image there and it will show?

Comment: nope! the images that have the same path are showing when i add them as line items in HTML, but no image will show at all in the background image.

Comment: What I'm asking you to do is insert the exact same path name of an image you know is working into that spot.

Comment: I have, not working. I tried moving the position and repeat tags to their own line, and the image shows up, but then the repeat and position are messed up.

Comment: Yes. There is an issue with accessing that image that we can't see. I can duplicate what you just saw. Are you sure you have permissions set properly on that image? Can you access it by http://your-site.com/imgs/heron.jpg? If not, can you access an image with http://your-site.com/imgs/good-image.jpg? If so, this is a server settings or configuration issue.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if tried already, but shurely you missed quotes here:

```
background: url("imgs/heron.jpg") no-repeat center top;
```